# Why is my Default Apache Guacamole Web Client Admin Login Creds Invalid?

Tags: mysql, authentication, rdp, ubuntu-22.04

I'm currently setting up an Ubuntu server to run an Apache Guacamole RDP Gateway, and for some reason, when I try to login to the web client, it's giving me an invalid login error when I use the default admin login credentials (according to Apache Guacamole documentation, being guacadmin for both username and password). I've looked at the logs, and I confirmed that it is indeed throwing invalid login. I'm pretty sure mySQL is configured properly with my server, although I'm not 100% sure because this is the first time I'm using mySQL and I'm following a guide to setup this RDP Gateway, but the reason I'm "pretty sure" is because I haven't had an error thrown at me in the CLI yet during this process. But since the default login creds come from the mySQL configuration, there's most likely an error with my configuration but I'm unsure where I went wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Welcome and thank you for posting. Getting good answers requires a clear and useful question which is [well written](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) , [on-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) and contains sufficient details to provide you with a good solution. Please copy-paste  relevant server configuration & settings, log excerpts and/or error messages into your question. - Please improve your question to address those points or run the risk of leaving your problem unresolved and/or having your question closed.